# Nested ngContainers and unit tests

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

we have a page that shows some data in a table. Data can be edited by clicking an icon. If so, a form with input elements is displayed instead of the table. When the user submits the form, the data is sent via POST to the endpoint. When the response contains a condition, one of the input elements is replaced with a select element. That is, we have 2 nested `ngContainers`. First one to display the edit form instead of the table, second one to replace the input element with the select element. This works fine so far. But in a unit test we want to ensure that we have a select element instead of an input element. We perform a query by id, but this fails. The query runs inside a block `fixture.whenStable().then(() => {...})` to handle Angular's asynchronous behavior.
Any help greatly appreciated. Kibu